# Manually Delete Records from PrincipalObjectAccess in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

After looking around for how to safely delete records from this huge PrincipalObjectAccess table, the most relevant post appears to be https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2664150

But it only cleaned up a fraction (8k out of 8 million records).

Then I found the Dynamics CRM won't delete records from PrincipalObjectAccess if you remove shared right. Instead, it will set AccessRightsMask=0.
And records with AccessRightsMask=0 constitute 40% of all records in PrincipalObjectAccess. Not sure whether it's safe to remove them.
Another finding is PrincipalObjectAccess has a large proportion of records relate to users being disabled (left the company). They take up almost half of our existing records. Are they also safe to remove?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the size of the POA table causing a problem for your system (eg, speed)?

Of the records that have AccessRightsMask==0, do these have a value in InheritedAccessRightsMask? If so, then these records are required. They're generated by CRM to propogate sharing from parent to child records.

Comment: if the POA table is very large, that is usually a symptom of a security design that needs some improvement.  If you are able to surgically clean out the table, I would also take a second look at your security model to ensure that it is optimized.